# An interview question: hot dog, chips, drink, meal (OO Design, Design Pattern. )

Tags: design-patterns, oop

Design a system about a food cart. Suppose you got hot dog, chips and drinks to sell and customers can also make it a meal.

1.Design a system for this situation.

2 What Design Patterns can you use here? Describe it?

Anybody can give me some hints? You can either give a brief idea or detailed description.
Thank you guys.

Comment: IT'S A TRAP! They're trying to trick you into over-engineering a trivial problem. That, or they're waiting for you to mention "Singleton" so they can all point and laugh.

Comment: that's ridiculous.. the question clearly says "**a** food cart", clearly implying that a Singleton has to be used here :)

Comment: @Anurag - no, a singleton would be the right pattern if they asked for "_THE_ food cart". Since they are asking for "a food cart", it's clear you could have more than one.

Comment: @Jim Lewis my assumption aswell.. design patterns? (other than inheritance and polymorphism LOL). Heck, I'd be satisfied with Meal={List<String>food;}

Comment: @Andy Leman - the easiest way to deal with this kind of interview questions is to start asking questions under the pretense of gathering specific requirements. You can easily kill the better part of an hour without actually answering anything.

Comment: @Franci Penov  thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FoodCartFactory that can produce multiple instances of FoodCart.

FoodCart is the main class.

You need to use IoC, since the cart should be indifferent to what type of food is sold. The cart has a hash table of instances of descendants of FoodItem abstract class, which represents the various items sold.

Using DI would also be a good idea, since the prices can vary depending on location and so on, so the factory has to configure the cart with a PolicyManager object that controls the prices.

Also, a FoodCartController would ensure that the cart is stocked with the right items.

You also need a CartCustomer object representing the target of the FoodSale message, which will contain the item, amount and price (including appropriate taxes, of course).

You also need some business logic, in a class called ProfitMaximizer, where the calculations of what is sold and how much, in order to pass the necessary FoodNeeded messages to the FoodController.

Of course, the ProfitMaximizer can't work well without some sort of analytics, probably in a class called FoodStatistics, which tracks sales, trends, margins, customer number and so on.

You also need some kind of diagnostics support, represented by class called FoodCartLogger, to collect information for diagnosing and troubleshooting problems with the cart.

Obviously, you also need to be concerned with the performance of the cart, so FoodCartPerfMonitor is waranted.

Then again, we should not skip over the possibility that this cart needs to serve customers in various location around the world, so you obviously need ResourceManager and FoodCartLocalizer.

You also need a subsystem to track the available capital, based on the income and expenses flow. Let's call it FoodCartAccountManager.

And if you have any profit left, it should be automatically invested to diversify the income, so of course ExchangeTrader class wouldn't be out of question.

Since the cart is manipulated by a person, you will also need Vendor class. Vendors tend to stay relatively shortly, so you will have a lot of churn you'll have to manage with a VendorManager class.

Of course, all these classes are necessary to control one cart; if you need to design a system that can deal with multiple carts, you'll have to add few other components. On the bright side, though, lot of the classes above obviously can deal with more than one cart, so you can reuse them.

I think that about covers the basic design.

Comment: rofl, but you could've thrown even more design patterns in there^^

Comment: really impressive. Let me think it through.

Comment: Doh! I forgot some obvious things like a CustomerQueueManager. Also, you'll likely end with concurrent requests to the cart, and you'll have to implement it as a free-threaded object.

Comment: @Dave O.  -hey, that's just a first stab. Obviously, I'll need at least a week to come up with a proper scalable distributed architecture, right separation of responsibilities between the components, good definition of the full food pipeline, and of course, let's not forget that we'll have to built good CDN for proper food distribution, with local caching for speeding up the cart access to the needed food items, and of course cache invalidation (through HealthManager class) to ensure food freshness. And I haven't even touched the government regulation facade.

Comment: Shoot, of course I forgot the view part of the MVC pattern. After all there should be some UI for the customers to interact with the food cart. (Although, if you're implementing the cart in WPF, some people might argue MVVM is the better pattern)

Comment: And the most important thing - proper SEO! Choose your cart URL carefully, as you want your cart to be easily discoverable by customers on Google. Throw in a dash of social networking as well, and keep your customers engaged with the food cart through Twitter and Facebook!

Comment: @Franci I'd love to see a "hello world" by you xD - no, stop, it was just a joke..

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this..

```
class FoodCart extends Vendor {
    List<FoodItem> foodItems;
    List<Meal> meals;
}

class Vendor {
    List<SellableItem> sellableItems;
    int saleRevenue;
}

class SellableItem {
    int price;
    int quantity;

    /**
     * @return true if the item is sold out
     */
    public boolean soldOut() {
        return quantity == 0;
    }
}

class FoodItem extends SellableItem {
    Date expirationDate;
    //more food-specific variables
}

class Meal {
    FoodItem[] foodItems;

    /**
     * The meal cannot be sold if any one component making up the meal is sold out.
     * @return true, if none of this meal's components is sold out.
     */
    boolean sellable() {
        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < foodItems.getLength(); i++) {
            result &= !foodItems[i].soldOut();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And there it is. Drinks are FoodItems as well. Tell me what you think.

Comment: I think we need to add Customer Class, this is interviewer asked me when interviewing. And customer got some methods, like askPrice() buy()  ...this is what I came up.

Comment: "class FoodCart extends Vendor"? How exactly can a cart be a vendor?

Comment: @kotlinski It's not a question of real world logic, it's a question of modeling. I can write a program where a fish is a bird :-P

Comment: IMO it would make more sense to model that with has-a rather than is-a.

Comment: @kotlinski Vendors sell items. A FoodCart sells a specific type of item. Therefore it is a Vendor.

Comment: @Darkhydro - actually, the FoodCart class is not concerned about what types of items are sold. In fact, I've seen quite a lot food carts where they'd sell anything, as long as it's in there and the customer has the cash.

Comment: @Darkhydro no prob but one question though: Do you see syntax highlighting? Because I only see black text.. =/